# MkDocs does not work properly with custom URL path

Tags: url, url-rewriting, kubernetes, mkdocs

Currently I'm using `mkdocs, version 1.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mkdocs (Python 2.7)`
With `mkdocs-material-3.0.4` theme.

I generated a static site using command `mkdocs build` and trying to deploy it. All site files are generated and use relative paths to static content (for ex. `js/something.js`).

The problem is that I need to use it from URL `https://internal.domain.com/docs/`. But I can not find the configuration to specify a relative path to generate paths with prefix (for ex. `docs/js/something.js`).

On the server side, I'm using k8s + ingress with rewrite rule (from `https://internal.domain.com/docs/` to `https://docs_service/).

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: You say relative URLs are working fine. And MkDocs uses relative URLs because they work regardless of location. Therefore I don't understand what your problem is? Please edit your question to include the Markdown source text, the generated HTML and the HTML you expected.

Comment: Also why are you using a rewrite rule to point to a different domain? MkDocs is a **static file generator**. You should not need to proxy from one server to another. Just copy the generated files to the root of the public server. Regardless, I hope you are not using the included server (`mkdocs serve`) in production as it is ***not*** intended for that purpose.

Comment: Is it working at all? Does it work if you go to `https://docs_service/`? I don't get what's working and not working. Do you want to use the ingress for path-based access?

Comment: @Waylan, @Rico, thanks for the responses.
I have static content deployed as a container with a simple web server inside to be able to proxy traffic to it from k8s ingress.
`https://docs_service/` is working. I've checked it first =)

And I've already fixed it. The problem was between the keyboard and chair =) Problem was with the trailing slash. Users who used `.../docs` URL was not able to load content, so I've added force redirect to `.../docs/`